# Record video with image or file as background PIP mode in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a requirement in my RN app that users can record a video and upload to the server. Before start recording, he can upload a picture or PDF file and the file should be in PIP mode. We need to record the video along with the file he uploaded and send it to the server. Can someone please suggest examples? Or guide me on how to implement this. Attached image for reference.

[image]
[image]

As you see in the picture, the user uploaded a pdf file and start recording. The PDF file is in the right corner and the recorded video should have the pdf as in the image. Please guide me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.